# Soft question: Examples where implications derived from mathematical models failed to describe reality

Tags: soft-question, math-history, philosophy

I have always been fascinated by how well conclusions drawn from mathematical models could fit reality, so I wondered if there are any counter examples.

In "Gödel, Escher, Bach" I could already find some pathological examples where axiomatic models seem to fit something like addition, but its implications do not fit anymore–however, I would like to know if there are any (historical) real world examples of something like this.

***Wall of text for clarification:*** I would be very grateful if answers could be split up into the two categories **"assumptions were not correct"** (e.g. pre-relativistic physical models when gravity was thought to be exerted instantly over any arbitrary distance or economic models that did not take Newcomblike-problems into account) and **"the mathematical models fit observed reality, however their implications do not anymore"** (or the ones that cannot be made correct by adjusting assumptions). Latter might seem impossible as we are talking about *implications*, but equivalence or implications are only defined within our "arbitrary" axiomatic system. So while you may argue that our models are defined in order to reflect reality (e.g. our concept of natural numbers), they can only do so marginally as even the existence of their majority (e.g. irrational (Pythagoreans), negative and imaginary (pretty much every mathematician at the time) numbers) has been disputed to a great extent. So I came to the conclusion that it is a nice "coincidence" that these models, relying on so many little helpers, really seem to be equivalent to observed reality.

Comment: I'd say that given the right premises, then the model works. If it does not work, it's not the logic's fault but the premises'. At least in the "real world".

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/feb/12/black-scholes-equation-credit-crunch

Comment: Every scientific theory (which at least as of the last 400-500 years have been mathematical models) that has ever been supplanted (proved wrong) made predictions that did not describe reality.  Newton's theory of gravity perhaps isn't a great example, but still by not predicting things like Mercury's precession, it essentially predicted the wrong thing.  Perhaps a more convincing "blunder" is classical statistical mechanics which predicted the so-called ultraviolet catastrophe (which everyone knew was nonsensical--hence "catastrophe"): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe

Answer (score 4):

Euclidean geometry.

I am asked to enter at least 30 characters, hence this additional sentence.

Answer (score 2):

As geodude said, if the premises are correct then the conclusions are correct.  However, some models used in mathematics do not reflect reality.

A Turing machine is one example.  Even if infinite memory is theoretically possible, accessing any part of memory in constant time is not.  This is why most mathematical analysis of runtime aren't exactly correct (off by a factor of a polylogarithm), but you probably won't notice unless you do hardware design.

Comment: I have a hard time being able to relate to this - if premises are correct, then the conclusions are correct _within the formal system_ we are working in, but not necessarily for "reality". (I edited the original question accordingly)
(I hope geodude is not sore, but I am answering to this point here, as it is hard to keep track of a discussion going on in the original question's comment section)

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding exactly the point of the question in the first place.  First off, this answer doesn't make sense to me.  "If the premises are correct then the conclusions are correct".  No, if the premises are correct _and_ your argument is valid, then the conclusions are correct, i.e. your argument is both sound (the premises are correct) and valid (the logic is correct).  The problem with reality is that there is no starting point from which you can claim any premise to be absolutely correct and thus no matter how valid your argument, it can never be logically sound.

Comment: If you could elaborate on why this question is pointless, this would be an answer as well I guess - to be honest I'm not feeling overly proficient here :)
The problem you are addressing in the last paragraph pretty much sums up my amazement that theories can describe reality so well and even lead to progression and as there are so many examples where it "just works" nonetheless, I was wondering if there are counterexamples as well.

Comment: Also: If _premises_ are correct (and your argument is valid), does this also mean every conclusion (in particular every proof within the system) may be applied to reality as well? Theoretically I could define an axiomatic system with another multiplication and feed it with some "perfectly accurate" and sound real world data, make some proofs, but most likely the proven results will not have anything to do with reality anymore.

Comment: It's not that I was saying the question was pointless, it's that I didn't quite understand what exactly the question was asking (i.e. what the point was).  I have little doubt that you could create a strange axiomatic system which somehow manipulated numbers in an unfamiliar way, yet when fed in real world data, an intelligent being could somehow reason as to why this strange number system produces the results we see in reality and then create some theory for reality based on this weird number system.

Comment: The distinction of whether or not you consider rules of inference to be assumptions or not is arbitrary, arguing over them is just arguing vocabulary.  To your question Peter, there is not a universal consensus on logic.  Different logics have different rules of inferences.  If you want, feel free to make up a logic whose rules of inferences don't reflect reality; no one is stopping you.  If you are interested in established logics that have been found in error, look up paradoxes, there have been a few, I believe Churchhill's logic had one.

Comment: @Jared: this fact that our axiomatic system is not just one of those "strange ones", but really seems to match reality is what fascinates me and my question was if this really is always the case (in particular whether there are specific counterexamples of theories that are sound and valid, but do not yield results relevant to real world)

Comment: @DanielV: did Churchill also do mathematics or is this a joke? ~.^ Apart from that: thanks for the hint to paradoxes, still wondering why I didn't think of those before...

Comment: @Peter Strange means unfamiliar.  Now, I do suspect that things like algebra and most of logic are emergent properties.  This explains why both Newton and Leibniz could independently come up with the same algebra of calculus.  Or is it explained because they are both human beings?  Perhaps an alien species uses something completely different to describe reality equally well as we do.  Yet their "math" might seem extremely strange to us and likewise, our math might seem extremely strange to them.  This is pure conjecture--as I believe that an alien species' math would be very similar to ours.

Comment: So perhaps Zeno's paradoxes is an example of what the question is looking for.  My problem is that his logic was incorrect.  Basically he had an invalid argument so it's not surprising his conclusions were wrong (i.e. he concluded there was a paradox where there was none).  There are formal methods for verifying whether a mathematical statement is valid or not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_prover However, most mathematical theorems are written in first order logic (i.e. for all integers ...) and, in general, first order logic is undecidable.

Comment: @Peter oops, I meant Alanzo Church, not Churchhill

Comment: @Jared: That's a pleasant point of view, however: Is there an objective criterion that distinguishes the "common", emergent axiomatic systems from others except that it seems to "fit reality"? (I guess the devil is in the details here, as 1+1=2 seems intuitively clear, but there are several ways to define a system in which this (and other basic assumptions) hold true)

Comment: Zeno's paradox seems to be a falsidical one (sticking to Quine's classification); guess I've just been looking for antinomies (like Russel's), as their reasoning is correct, but their implications are "kind of false" (contradictory).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't Gödel's second incompleteness theorem mean that even arithmetic cannot describe reality perfectly ? I am making the assumption that in reality everything is either true or false. I know this is sloppy wording and I feel like putting most of my words in quotes. What I mean is that my gut says that for example, in reality the Continuum hypothesis is either true or false. There's either a set with a higher cardinality than natural numbers, but lower than reals, or not.

Comment: If we make the assumption that all well-formed formulas are part of reality, then yes. But that is a rather bold claim; I don't feel comfortable saying that any infinite set is "real" in (e.g.) the Platonic sense.

Comment: Fair enough. So are there Gödel sentences that have to do with something that can be mapped to something "tangible" ?

Answer (score 2):

The paradox known as the [Banach-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) would have it that you can take a unit ball, subdivide it into 5 parts, move those parts around by rigid motions, and reassemble them into... a *pair* of unit balls. This tends to go counter to physical assumptions such as conservation of mass, etc. The official explanation usually given is that the "parts" in question are of a particularly nettlesome kind known as "nonmeasurable". This does not take away from the fact that the paradox tends to go counter to what natural scientists would expect to happen. The "mathematical existence", as it were, of such sets is a consequence of a nonconstructive set-theoretic axiom known as the [axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).